# Show angular $log in gulp tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, yeoman-generator

I've set up Angular.js scaffolding using the [Gulp Angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md) generator. In tests, I inject $log

When running `gulp test` if I `$log.debug("something")` it don't appear in the console output, however console.log does.

- Question: Where do the logs get output to?
- Question: How can I make the logs appear in the console output?

Comment: What browser are you using to run the tests? PhantomJS or something else?

Comment: Phil, console output says PhantomJS